# R data.table merge / full outer join with na.fill / nomatch based on formula

Tags: r, data.table, zoo, full-outer-join

What I need is to perform full outer join with some kind of smart na.fill / nomatch in a efficient way. I've already done it using loop but I would like to use matrix algebra or data.table operations to speed up the process.

Data below are sample of stock open orders information, full outer join is performed between datasets of asks open orders and bids open orders. A dataset are asks, B are bids. Both datasets stores atomic orders and their cumulative sums. The task is to match all ask orders with bid orders by cumulative value and vice versa.
Populate example data:

```
price = c(11.25,11.26,11.35,12.5,14.2)
amount = c(1.2,0.4,2.75,6.5,15.2)
A <- data.table(ask_price = price, ask_amount = amount, ask_cum_amount = cumsum(amount), cum_value = cumsum(price*amount), ask_avg_price = cumsum(price*amount)/cumsum(amount))
price = c(11.18,11.1,10.55,10.25,9.7)
amount = c(0.15,0.6,10.2,3.5,12)
B <- data.table(bid_price = price, bid_amount = amount, bid_cum_amount = cumsum(amount), cum_value = cumsum(price*amount), bid_avg_price = cumsum(price*amount)/cumsum(amount))
```

regular full outer join and it's results:

```
setkey(A, cum_value)
setkey(B, cum_value)
C <- merge(A,B,all=TRUE)
print(C)
```

na.fill / nomatch **pseudocode** formula, for every row (ask or bid) where cum_value not matches (please keep in mind that every other field than cum_value is related to ask OR bid):

```
avg_price["current NA"] <- cum_value["last non NA"]/cum_value["current NA"] * avg_price["last non NA"] + (1-cum_value["last non NA"]/cum_value["current NA"]) * price["next non NA"]
cum_amount["current NA"] <- cum_value["current NA"] / avg_price["current NA"]
```

expected results:

```
D <- data.table(
  cum_value = c(1.677,8.337,13.5,18.004,49.2165,115.947,130.4665,151.822,268.222,346.3065),
  ask_price = c(NA,NA,11.25,11.26,11.35,NA,12.5,NA,NA,14.2),
  ask_amount = c(NA,NA,1.2,0.4,2.75,NA,6.5,NA,NA,15.2),
  ask_cum_amount = c(0.149066666666667,0.741066666666667,1.2,1.6,4.35,9.66496172396059,10.85,12.3126600707381,20.4097766460076,26.05),
  ask_avg_price = c(11.25,11.25,11.25,11.2525,11.31414,11.9966331281534,12.02456,12.3305605066459,13.1418390633132,13.29392),
  bid_price = c(11.18,11.1,NA,NA,NA,10.55,NA,10.25,9.7,NA),
  bid_amount = c(0.15,0.6,NA,NA,NA,10.2,NA,3.5,12,NA),
  bid_cum_amount = c(0.15,0.75,1.23858478466587,1.66517233847558,4.6230572556498,10.95,12.3652404387114,14.45,26.45,NA),
  bid_avg_price = c(11.18,11.116,10.8995364444444,10.8120940902022,10.6458772362927,10.58877,10.5510685899445,10.50671,10.14072,NA)
)
print(D)
```

Note that in the expected results the last NA is still as NA, this is because opposite order could not be matched because the market depth is not enough to fulfill the order at any price.

Is it possible to get expected results using matrix algebra or data.table operations or any other efficient way to avoid looping over full dataset?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Your formula uses `avg_price` and `price` neither of which are present in any of your `data.table`s. Could you clarify?

Comment: @Arun, formula to calc ask_avg_price uses ask_*, formula to calc bid_avg_price uses bid_*, only cum_value field is common for both sets and should not be prefixed by ask/bid in the formula.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Merge it back again with `A` and `B` with a `roll` to find the last/next non-NA prices.

E.g. see the output values of `bid_avg_price` for these two merges:

```
B[merge(A, B, all = T), roll = Inf]
B[merge(A, B, all = T), roll = -Inf]
```

That should give you all the info you need to compute those quantities.

Comment: Thank you, using your suggestion I was able to: 1. join A and B with unique(c(A_key,B_key)), 2. perform self-joins for A and B to get prev non-NA and next non-NA, 3. merge already NA-filled A and B and get expected results. Cpu time is outstanding. The code is 15th lines long and it doesn't looks enough readable. I think it still can be improved. After few weeks break it will be tough to read it. Thanks anyway, some new skill gained!

Comment: @MusX I'd understand this operation if the order book was crossed (as in auction) and you were finding the price that maximised the fill volume (uncrossing price), for example. But in the example the book isn't crossed: best bid < best ask, as normal in continuous session. Have I missed something?

Comment: @MatthewDowle, As in the example, asks/bids from order book are not crossing, if they were crossed they would not be listed in order book but in the past transactions (filled orders). The point of the operation is to match asks to bids and bids to asks by it's cum value. The result which comes from this operation is avg_price(cum_value) as formula (ask_avg_price(cum_value)+bid_avg_price(cum_value))/2, and this avg_price shows the distribution of open orders in it's cumulative values. I will be happy to hear a comment about my logic, it's kind of DIY with no financial knowledge background.

Comment: @MusX Yes a crossed book (where bid>ask) is possible and observed every day ... in an auction (intra day auction usually on less liquid stocks, or closing auction for all stocks, depending on market). I think I understand what you want to do, but I don't see why you want to do that. The closing price of an auction (the uncrossing price) is very similar to what you're describing (but on the crossed portion of the book in the auction). Are you sure you don't want to do that?

Comment: @MatthewDowle, 1. my assumption is that crossed book is not possible (I cannot observe such case on bitcoin market - kind of forex currency exchange). 2. why: I would like to use avg_price(cum_value) as indicator/factor for buy/sell signals. Following graph is closely related to my logic: http://i.imgur.com/jnOenMx.png
X axis: price,
Y axis: cum value,
orange line: bid_avg_price,
blue line: ask_avg_price,
green line: past transaction - ignore this,
On the graph there are only ask_avg_price and bid_avg_price with no avg_price of both of them.